# Camera2 and Renderscript Allocations

Tags: android, renderscript, android-camera2

I'm trying to use an Allocation created with the USING_IO_INPUT flag to get images from the camera. I'm setting it up as follows

```
Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.YUV(mRS));
                yuvType.setYuvFormat(imageReaderFormat);
                yuvType.setX(mCameraWidth).setY(mCameraHeight);
mAllocation = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, yuvType.create(), Allocation
                        .MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                        Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
mAllocation.setOnBufferAvailableListener(mOnBufferAllocationAvailable);
```

I'm adding the Allocation surface to a Preview Session, and getting the callbacks to my very simple function

```
public void onBufferAvailable(Allocation allocation) {
     allocation.ioReceive();
     //mPixels is properly initialised
     allocation.copyTo(mPixels);
}
```

This setup works on a Nexus 5X, but fails on a Nexus 4 running 5.1.1. When I call `allocation.ioReceive()` in the callback, I get a few warnings printed from the driver, and copying from the Allocation to a byte array results in garbage being copied.

```
W/Adreno-RS: <rsdVendorAllocationUnMapQCOM:394>: NOT Found allocation map for alloc 0xa1761000
W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:427>: ioctl fd 25 code 0xc01c0915 (IOCTL_KGSL_MAP_USER_MEM) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
W/Adreno-RS: <rsdVendorAllocationMapQCOM:288>: gsl_memory_map_fd failed -5 hostptr: 0xa0112000 sz: 0 offset: 0 flags: 0x10c0b00 alloc: 0xa1761000
```

I am running the camera in a background thread, although `onBufferAvailable` gets called in the "RSMessageThread".

Is this problem related to the way I am setting the Allocations and the Camera Preview, or is it a bug in the driver?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the official [HDR-viewfinder example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder)? If this works on the Nexus 4, then you can study that example.

If not, you can try with my implementation [YUV_420_888 to Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212904/yuv-420-888-interpretation-on-samsung-galaxy-s7-camera2) that uses a different approach, not via YUV-allocations but via byte-allocation using the Information from the three image planes.

Answer (score 0):

I see the same error message on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Smart Phone), android version 5.0 (API 21), but do not with the identical application using camera2 and renderscript, on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 5 (Tablet), android version 5.1.1 (API 22).  I'm assuming it is an early implementation problem on the device vendors part.

Comment: In the meantime it is well known, that API 21 is not yet fit for Camera2. Start using it for API>= 22.