# How to do fast memory copy from YUV_420_888 to NV21

Tags: java, android, c++, yuv, nv12-nv21

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726002/camera2-captured-picture-conversion-from-yuv-420-888-to-nv21/52740776#52740776), I want to write a method converting android [YUV_420_888](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat#YUV_420_888) to nv21. A more general implementation is needed although image from camera2 API is default NV21 in disguise. It is as follows:

```java
class NV21Image{
public byte[] y;
public byte[] uv;
}

public static void cvtYUV420ToNV21(Image image, NV21Image nv21) {
        int width  = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int ySize  = width*height;
        ByteBuffer yBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer(); // Y
        ByteBuffer uBuffer = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer(); // U
        ByteBuffer vBuffer = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer(); // V

        int yRowStride = image.getPlanes()[0].getRowStride();
        int vRowStride = image.getPlanes()[2].getRowStride();
        int pixelStride = image.getPlanes()[2].getPixelStride();
        assert(image.getPlanes()[0].getPixelStride() == 1);
        assert(image.getPlanes()[2].getRowStride() == image.getPlanes()[1].getRowStride());
        assert(image.getPlanes()[2].getPixelStride() == image.getPlanes()[1].getPixelStride());

        int pos = 0;
        int yBufferPos = -yRowStride; // not an actual position
        for (; pos<ySize; pos+=width) {
            yBufferPos += yRowStride;
            yBuffer.position(yBufferPos);
            yBuffer.get(nv21.y, pos, width);
        }

        pos = 0;
        for (int row=0; row<height/2; row++) {
            for (int col=0; col<vRowStride / pixelStride; col++) {
                int vuPos = col*pixelStride + row * vRowStride;
                nv21.uv[pos++] = vBuffer.get(vuPos);
                nv21.uv[pos++] = uBuffer.get(vuPos);
            }
        }
}
```

Above codes work as expected while very time-consuming for my live camera preview app(about 12ms per frame of 720p in Snapdragon 865 CPU), So I tried to accelerate it with JNI implementation to take profit from the byte-access and performance advantages:

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_Utils_nFillYUVArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jbyteArray yArr, jbyteArray uvArr,
                                                 jobject yBuf, jobject uBuf, jobject vBuf,
                                                 jint yRowStride, jint vRowStride, jint vPixelStride, jint w, jint h) {
    auto ySrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(yBuf);
    auto uSrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(uBuf);
    auto vSrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(vBuf);

    for(int row = 0; row < h; row++){
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(yArr, row * w, w, ySrcPtr + row * yRowStride);
    }

    int pos = 0;
    for (int row=0; row<h/2; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col<w/2; col++) {
            int vuPos = col * vPixelStride + row * vRowStride;
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(uvArr, pos++, 1, vSrcPtr + vuPos);
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(uvArr, pos++, 1, uSrcPtr + vuPos);
        }
    }
}
```

However, it get worse than I expected(about 107ms per frame). **And the most time-consuming part is interlaced memory copying for UV buffer**
So my problem is Whether any ways to accelerate and how to work it out?

**Update**
I accelerated it successfully(check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74664054/8110010)) when `pixelStride`s of U,V plane are both 1 or 2, I believe it is what happening in most cases.

Comment: Can you separate the 10 ms in three? Until the for loop. And of both for loops. We wanna know where to look first.

Comment: I've been working on similar topic (conversion+rotation) for few weeks and my advice is: just forget writing own methods, native or Java, just use [libyuv](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/) (well, "just" is wrong word in here, I've been struggling with this lib implementation for long, but got it work, performance 4x time faster than fastest of previously tried solutions for my problems)

Answer (score 0):

As @snachmsm said libyuv might help. I found an available API [`I420ToNV21`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/libyuv/libyuv/+/refs/heads/stable/include/libyuv/convert_from.h#116), But it cannot receive [pixelStride](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image.Plane#getPixelStride()) parameter, for `YUV_420_888` does not guarantee no gaps exist between adjacent pixels in U,V planes.
I accelerated it successfully with arm intrinsics when the pixelStride is 2(**reduce to 2.7ms per frame**):

```cpp
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_Utils_nFillYUVArray(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jbyteArray yArr, jbyteArray uvArr,
                                                 jobject yBuf, jobject uBuf, jobject vBuf,
                                                 jint yRowStride, jint vRowStride, jint uRowStride, jint pixelStride,
                                                 jint width, jint height) {
    ///TODO: too time-consuming
    auto ySrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(yBuf);
    auto uSrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(uBuf);
    auto vSrcPtr = (jbyte const*)env->GetDirectBufferAddress(vBuf);

    for(int row = 0; row < height; row++){
        env->SetByteArrayRegion(yArr, row * width, width, ySrcPtr + row * yRowStride);
    }

    constexpr int kStride = 8;
    const size_t nGroups = width / kStride;
    if(pixelStride == 2){
        int8_t *line = (int8_t*)alignedAlloc(width, 64);
        int8_t *mask = (int8_t*)alignedAlloc(kStride, 64);
        memset(mask, 0, kStride);
        for(int i=0; i < kStride / 2; i++) {
            mask[i * 2] = -1;
        }
        int8x8_t vm = vld1_s8(mask);

        for(int row = 0; row < height / 2; row ++){
            size_t vrowOff = row * vRowStride;
            size_t urowOff = row * uRowStride;
            for(int g = 0; g < nGroups; g++) {
                size_t colOff = g * kStride;
                int8x8_t v0  = vld1_s8(vSrcPtr + vrowOff + colOff);
                int8x8_t v1  = vld1_s8(uSrcPtr + urowOff + colOff);
                int8x8_t a0  = vand_s8(v0, vm);
                int16x4_t b1 = vreinterpret_s16_s8(vand_s8(v1, vm));
                int8x8_t a1  = vreinterpret_s8_s16(vshl_n_s16(b1, 8));
                int8x8_t r = vorr_s8(a0, a1);
                vst1_s8(line + colOff, r);
            }
            env->SetByteArrayRegion(uvArr, row * width, width, line);
        }

        free(mask);
        free(line);
    }else if(pixelStride == 1){
        int8_t *line = (int8_t*)alignedAlloc(width, 64);
        for(int row = 0; row < height / 2; row ++) {
            size_t vrowOff = row * vRowStride;
            size_t urowOff = row * uRowStride;
            for(int g = 0; g < nGroups / 2; g++){
                size_t colOff = g * kStride;
                int8x8_t v0 = vld1_s8(vSrcPtr + vrowOff + colOff);
                int8x8_t v1 = vld1_s8(uSrcPtr + urowOff + colOff);
                int8x8x2_t vz = vzip_s8(v0, v1);

                vst1_s8(line + colOff, vz.val[0]);
                vst1_s8(line + colOff + kStride, vz.val[1]);
            }

            env->SetByteArrayRegion(uvArr, row * width, width, line);
        }
        free(line);
    }
}
```

**Case of `pixelStride == 1` is not tested sufficiently**, but I believe it will work as expected.

Comment: can't find "alignedAlloc, int8x8_t, vld1_s8, int16x4_t, vorr_s8" -> where do I find the missing params/methods?

Comment: @kfir you should include the header of `arm_neon.h` and `alignedAlloc` is a thin wrapper of [`memalign`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign), it is safe to use `memalign` instead