Efficient YUV to RGB (Image to Bitmap) conversion in Android
I'm trying to apply YUV (Media.Image) to RGB (Bitmap) conversion in Android. I am currently using this official code from Android Camera samples (the code below) but it uses RenderScript which is going to be deprecated.
I developed the following function but it is not efficient and it takes 2x-3x more time to execute compared the official Renderscript-based code.
How can I rewrite it to be nearly as efficient as the RenderScript solution? Any Android native solutions available?
   public Bitmap imageToBitmap(Image image, float rotationDegrees) {

        assert (image.getFormat() == ImageFormat.YUV_420_888);

        // NV21 is a plane of 8 bit Y values followed by interleaved  Cb Cr
        ByteBuffer ib = ByteBuffer.allocate(image.getHeight() * image.getWidth() * 2);

        ByteBuffer y = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer cr = image.getPlanes()[1].getBuffer();
        ByteBuffer cb = image.getPlanes()[2].getBuffer();
        ib.put(y);
        ib.put(cb);
        ib.put(cr);

        YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(ib.array(),
                ImageFormat.NV21, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0,
                image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 50, out);
        byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        Bitmap bitmap = bm;

        return bitmap;
    }


Have you taken a look at the SO answer that is linked in the KDoc? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726002/camera2-captured-picture-conversion-from-yuv-420-888-to-nv21/52740776#52740776

The link uses private fun Image.toByteArray(outputBuffer: ByteArray) which is also a part of this YuvToRgbConverter.kt file I shared. But I need to convert it to a Bitmap afterwards.

I added my inefficient solution

Have you seen: https://github.com/android/renderscript-intrinsics-replacement-toolkit/tree/main but do check the issues: https://github.com/android/renderscript-intrinsics-replacement-toolkit/issues

@MorrisonChang should I simply use ReferenceYuvToRgb.kt? I looked at it but why it still uses import com.google.android.renderscript.YuvFormat?

If you are using CameraX see ImageAnalysis / Convert from planar YUV to RGB using CameraX, if you are not using CameraX see: https://github.com/gordinmitya/yuv2buf

I still couldn't find a way to do it. It was so complex. If you know a snippet, please write it as an answer and I can mark as answer

Btw, the Toolkit says: Add support for YUV_420_888 in the future. Apparently it's not supported yet
