# How to consider pixelStride in conversion of YUV to RGB using a fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera2

This shader works perfectly for Android devices running on API 21

Where pixelStride is 1 and uvRowStride is 320 (preview resolution 640x480)

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D y_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D v_texture;

void main()
{   
  float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;
  nx=v_texCoord.x;
  ny=v_texCoord.y;
  y=texture2D(y_texture,v_texCoord).r;
  u=texture2D(u_texture,v_texCoord).r;
  v=texture2D(v_texture,v_texCoord).r;

  y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);
  u=u-0.5;
  v=v-0.5;

  r=y+1.5958*v;
  g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;
  b=y+2.017*u;

  gl_FragColor = vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
}
```

But in Android devices with API 22+ is always having

pixelStride is 2 and uvRowStride is 640 (preview resolution 640x480)

References: https://github.com/wenxiaoming/YUVRender

[YUV_420_888 interpretation on Samsung Galaxy S7 (Camera2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212904/yuv-420-888-interpretation-on-samsung-galaxy-s7-camera2)

Top part of image shows converted YUV in GLSurfaceView, bottom part shows actual colour in normal TextureView

[image: Image with normal camera preview and GLSurfaceView]

**Edit**:

Work around not depending on shader to do pixelStride calculation was to input U & V byte buffer without any strides. Performance is lower than pure shader code.

How to integrate the below code to shader? (I am really bad with shaders)

```
 private static Buffer getByteBufferWithoutStrides(int pixelStride, ByteBuffer byteBuffer){
    byteBuffer.position(0);
    byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
    byteBuffer.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    byte[] noStrides = new byte[bytes.length/2];
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< noStrides.length; i++){
        noStrides[i] = bytes[j];
        j+= pixelStride;
    }
    bytes = null;
    byteBuffer.clear();
    Buffer noStridesBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(noStrides);

    return noStridesBuffer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not perform YUV conversion in the shader, this is non-trivial since there are several kinds of YUV formats.  Instead, use `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` and sample from it like you would a traditional RGB texture.  See the Android docs for [SurfaceTexture](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture).

Comment: This has an added advantage that is that this is often also normally faster, because most mobile GPUs have native support for sampling YUV surfaces.

Comment: I was creating a 2 or 3 frames delayed camera preview, by saving previous frames as byte[]. Let me try if it is possible this way. Currently solved the issue by a work around by removing stride from byte[] before feeding it to shader. Now it takes around 2 - 6 ms for conversion.

Comment: Is there more than 2 types of YUV format when targeting devices above API 21?

Comment: There are *many* types of YUV format - both in terms of pixel layout and color encoding (wide vs narrow gamut). Exactly what you get on any specific device is vendor dependent - but if you use the `GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES` you don't need to worry about it.