# Renderscript Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) fault addr

Tags: android, android-ndk, rgb, renderscript, yuv

I am using the camera2 API to get a stream of images of format `ImageFormat.YUV_420_888`. I need to do some processing on them with a library that requires sending the image as an RGB byte array (so the `byte array length = width * height * 3`)

I used [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212904/yuv-420-888-interpretation-on-samsung-galaxy-s7-camera2) (and also probably all the others) to convert the Image into an RGB byte array (which seems to be working, at least the result byte array is the one I need).

Also, here is the exact code I used to convert the YUV_420 to RGB, in Kotlin, with some updates: https://gist.github.com/VictorMotogna/e7a8493af65be994f29f5508660dd4a9

The problem is that the conversion crashes with the message `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xe00000084 in tid 20776 (package name), pid 20776` after a few tries.

I've tried other image formats, other conversions, nothing seems to work - I either get the same crash (when using YUV_420 or NV21) or I can't get the correct image/conversion.

One thing that seemed to help was:
With `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` the app crashed after a lot more runs than with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Things I noticed in your example code:

- you destroy your allocations before you are finished using them (can be reused like the rs context)
- you define and set default launch options (not needed)